# How to configure CSS Mdoules with NWB on sass files

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules, nwb

I am creating a react component with NWB. The folder structure looks like below.

```
* components/
** src/
*** Component1/
**** index.js
**** index.module.scss
*** Component2/
** nwb.config.js
** package.json
```

How can I implement CSS modules in this structure? The problem is, style files not exporting to es (build, dist etc.) folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by editing the `build` script on `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nwb build-react-component --copy-files"
}
```